# Symfony2 - FOSRestBundle - Custom Serializer or JSON Output

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

How do you create a custom JSON output with FOSRestBundle?

The code already has methods which are used to convert entities and paginated result sets to JSON.  As well as generate unique URLs to view/edit the entities in the outputted JSON.

How can these be used with FOSRestBundle?

Example of custom method to convert Bars to JSON output:

```
    $json = $this->getJsonFactory('Bar')
        ->dataTableFormat($data);
    return $this->jsonResponse($json);
```

How can this custom method be used as the output for JSON from view?

```
    $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Foo:Bar')
        ->findAll();
    $view = $this->view($data, 200)
            ->setTemplate("Foo:Bar:index.html.twig")
            ->setTemplateVar('bars')
    ;
```

JMSSerializerBundle is available if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using custom handlers this is possible, see docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#custom-handler

Working example:

```
    $handler = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler');
    if (!$handler->isFormatTemplating($view->getFormat())) {
        $templatingHandler = function ($handler, $view, $request) {
            $data = $this->getJsonFactory('Bar')
                 ->dataTableFormat($$view->getData());
            $view->setData($data);
            return $handler->createResponse($view, $request, 'json');
        };
        $handler->registerHandler('json', $templatingHandler);
    }
```

The $templatingHandler method handles calling the JsonFactory and setting the formatting of data for json output.